# How to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04.1 to 14.04.2?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I want to run some software that was extensively tested against 14.04.2 and don't want to take the risk that 14.04.3 might be incompatible at some level.

So, How can I upgrade My machine form 14.04.01 to 14.04.02?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

14.04.2 and 14.04.3 are not "releases" in terms of "do-release-upgrade".

"Point" releases accumulate security updates and bug fixes that are added to Ubuntu repositories.

If you install ordinary updates on Ubuntu 14.04, 14.04.1 or 14.04.2, you will get 14.04.3.

So your goal makes no sense.

The only difference of the ISO of the point releases is [HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). Kernels are updated to another major version and xserver.

If this is your question you can install 3.16 kernel and graphical stack of 14.04.2 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-utopic libgles2-mesa-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

The command given in the official wiki [can brake your system](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/how-to-upgrade-to-the-3-16-lts-utopic-kernel-and-graphics-for-ubuntu-14-04/) in some cases.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect that means that the nearest I can get to the tested 14.04 environment is to install the utopic kernel (which is what the test environment used). For confirmation then, since I'm running the server version of 14.04, I think that means I need "sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic" - is that right?

Comment: For the server you do not need all other stuff. So you are correct. Just install the kernel. And it is very unlikely that other upgrades can affect something for a server.