# Is it possible to upgrade not to LTS? 16.04.2 to 16.04.4 for example (while 16.04.5 is LTS)

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, lts, versions

I need to update to a specific point version **not to LTS**, is it possible?

For example from:
16.04.2 to 16.04.4 (while 16.04.5 is LTS)

I don't want to mark specific files or packages just to use a simple solution to upgrade to a specific version.
Suggested solution below **is not** what I need:

[How to hold Ubuntu point release version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707784/how-to-hold-ubuntu-point-release-version)

Comment: What actually you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm writing drivers and got customer who uses specific version (16.04.3).

I have my test machines installed with 16.04.2 and I need them them at (04.3) to test drivers.